# need help in curl

Tags: shell-script, curl

Below command works fine when I ran my Windows desktop but it failed to find the resource if I ran from Linux server.

On windows this is how I am giving which is working.

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -u username:password -X GET http://10.188.102.94:23450/ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?$query=ldev.storageDeviceId%20eq%20'00000060489'
```

I tried this way as Quote before http but still failed on UNIX shell:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -u username:password 'http://10.188.102.94:23450/ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?$query=ldev.storageDeviceId%20eq%20%27900000060489'
```

Here it returns this error:

```
{
    "errorSource" : "/ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?=hostGroup.storageDeviceId%20eq%20900000060489",
    "message" : "Resource information could not be obtained.",
    "cause" : "The specified storage system is invalid.",
    "solution" : "Check and, if necessary, revise the query parameter to obtain information about the storage system."
}
```

Comment: The URL should be in single quotes as the metacharacters will give you problems. I see a trailing `'` but no leading `'`. Please edit your question to give the exact command you ran (redact the IP and usrname:password) and the exact error message.

Comment: @doneal24 The leading `'` is there, just before the `9`.

Comment: Missed it. Move the leading `'` t in front of `http`. Why would you quote a part of the URL that contains only digits?

Comment: curl -H Content-Type:application/json -H Accept:application/json -u username:password -X GET 'http://10.188.102.94:23450/ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?=hostGroup.storageDeviceId%20eq%20900000060489'
{
  "errorSource" : "/ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?=hostGroup.storageDeviceId%20eq%20900000060489",
  "message" : "Resource information could not be obtained.",
  "cause" : "The specified storage system is invalid.",
  "solution" : "Check and, if necessary, revise the query parameter to obtain information about the storage system.",

Comment: Is `$query` a variable or is it a literal parameter name?

Comment: when I put double quotes from "http until end it says curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl. also I moved single quote before as well but not working..  the one at end is serial number of array where I need to put in single quotes.  exact same command windows desktop is not working.. not changing anything

Comment: $query is parameter

Comment: C:\Users\agundra>curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -u username:password   -X GET http://10.188.102.94:23450/ConfigurationManaer/v1/views/lun-paths?$query=ldev.storageDeviceId%20eq%20'900000060489'
{
  "data" : [ {
    "hostGroup" : {
      "hostGroupId" : "CL1-A,1",
      "portId" : "CL1-A",
      "hostGroupNumber" : 1,
      "hostGroupName" : "pdk_mg_ifhds_01",
      "hostMode" : "WIN_EX",
      "resourceGroupId" : 0,
      "isDefined" : true,
      "storageDeviceId" : "900000060489"
    },
    "ldev" : {
      "ldevId" : 0,

Comment: `-X GET` makes no sense! `GET` is the default method, and using `-X` to specify it actually makes some of `curl`'s features harder to use.

Comment: @AneshKumar what you just showed there now is a windows prompt, so this isn't happening on Unix?

Comment: this is working fine on windows. its failing on unix shell. I tried using below command using Quote all URL but still failed with below error.                                                                       "errorSource" : "/ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?$query=ldev.storageDeviceId%20eq%20%27900000060489",
  "message" : "The format of the query parameter specified in the URL is invalid. (details = line 1, column 25:\nstring literal, DECIMAL, true or false expected, EOF encountered.)",

Comment: Please put your updates into the question. There you can format them. Make it easier for us to help you @AneshKumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your latest edit finally shows this as being successfully run on a Windows system:

> ```
> curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -u username:password -X GET http://10.188.102.94:23450/ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?$query=ldev.storageDeviceId%20eq%20'00000060489'
> ```

You have to remember that quoting rules for Windows CMD and a UNIX/Linux shell are completely different. Quote the URL and you're much more likely to have success, particularly as it appears one of the parameters is the literal `$query`, which for a UNIX/Linux shell would otherwise be interpreted as a variable to be expanded.

To confirm the quoting rules for Windows I ran your command in a Windows CMD window, changing the target IP address from 10.188.102.94 to the IP address for my Linux Server ("linuxServer") and running `nc -l 23450` there to create a listening port for the incoming request.

```
# Linux Server
nc -vvv -l 23450
Listening on linuxServer 23450

# Windows PC
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -u username:password -X GET http://linuxServer:23450/ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?$query=ldev.storageDeviceId%20eq%20'00000060489'
```

Output received (HTTP request) on the Linux Server:

```
Connection received on linuxServer 13252
GET /ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?$query=ldev.storageDeviceId%20eq%20'00000060489' HTTP/1.1
Host: linuxServer:23450
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
Content-Type:application/json
```

You can clearly see that the URL path contains embedded single quotes. It turns out that [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) says these characters are permitted, so although they are unusual they are acceptable. This means we need to quote them with double quotes to ensure they are not processed by the shell - but equally the `$query` text cannot be included in double quotes because it would otherwise be processed as a shell variable. Here I've chosen to single-quote the first part of the URL and then switch midway to using double quotes (`'abc'"def"` is processed as a single string `abcdef`):

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -u username:password 'http://linuxServer:23450/ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?$query=ldev.storageDeviceId%20eq%20'"'00000060489'"
```

Output received (HTTP request) on the Linux Server:

```
Connection received on linuxServer 13993
GET /ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?$query=ldev.storageDeviceId%20eq%20'00000060489' HTTP/1.1
Host: linuxServer:23450
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
Content-Type:application/json
```

It's the same so we have achieved the requirement. Replacing the IP address with your real one we finally have this solution:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -u username:password 'http://10.188.102.94:23450/ConfigurationManager/v1/views/lun-paths?$query=ldev.storageDeviceId%20eq%20'"'00000060489'"
```